# Is returning a resource instance from a function in a 'using' statement the same as instantiating the resource directly in the 'using' statement?

Tags: c#, using

I'm trying to conform to best practices for 'using' as defined here:

> You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case, the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged resources. In other words, it will no longer be fully initialized. If you try to use the object outside the using block, you risk causing an exception to be thrown. For this reason, it is generally better to instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to the using block.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

So given that rule, I think this is wrong:

```
private PrincipalContext GetDomainContext(
        out bool bFailedBecauseDomainServerIsInaccessible
        )
    {
        bFailedBecauseDomainServerIsInaccessible = false;

        try
        {
            return new PrincipalContext(
                ContextType.Domain,
                null
                );
        }
        catch (PrincipalServerDownException downEx)
        {
            bFailedBecauseDomainServerIsInaccessible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }

//calling logic...
PrincipalContext ctxDomain = null;
bool bErrorHittingDomainServer = false;
ctxDomain = GetDomainContext(
            out bErrorHittingDomainServer
            );
using (ctxDomain)
{
     //do stuff and automatically dispose when finished
}
```

Question is, if I use my same 'GetDomainContext' function and return PrincipalContext right in the 'using' statement does that still violate best practices per the Microsoft Doc?

```
using (ctxDomain = GetDomainContext(
    out bErrorHittingDomainServer
    ))
{
    //do stuff and automatically dispose when finished
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The using block is all about making certain "that Disposeable stuff is disposed when it is no longer needed".

Internally it is realised as (or something close to):

```
try{
  ctxDomain = GetDomainContext(out bErrorHittingDomainServer);
  //The other code inside the using block
}
finally{
 if(ctxDomain != null){
    ctxDomain.Dispose();
  }
}
```

My general rule for anything that is disposeable is:
Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a using block.

Splitting up the creation and diposing of anything diposeable is only asking for trouble down the line. Resist the temptation to do it for any reason - including performance - unless you actually work on the level where you handle Unamanged Resoruces **directly**. Most Disposeable classes are there so you only handle unamanged stuff indirectly.

Answer (score 3):

Your last block still violates the suggestion being made because the variable still exists (i.e. is *in scope*) after the `using` statement. The point trying to be made is that with your code you can do this:

```
PrincipalContext ctxDomain = null;
using (ctxDomain = GetDomainContext(
    out bErrorHittingDomainServer
    ))
{
    //do stuff and automatically dispose when finished
}

//This will throw a null reference exception at runtime
ctxDomain.DoStuff();
```

However, if your code is this:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctxDomain = GetDomainContext(
    out bErrorHittingDomainServer
    ))
{
    //do stuff and automatically dispose when finished
}

//This line of code won't even compile because the variable is not in scope here
ctxDomain.DoStuff();
```

So in the first block you can have a fatal exception at **runtime**, but the second will never allow you to compile in the first place.

Comment: Just a clarification on the first block of code: the call to DoStuff won't necessarily throw a null reference exception. The using does not set ctxDomain to null. What will happen will entirely depend on how DoStuff is designed to behave after a PrincipalContext has been disposed. It's possible that DoStuff doesn't rely on any of the resources that Dispose frees up and therefore will still work correctly, or it may specifically check some internal state that indicates disposal and throws an ObjectDisposedException.

Answer (score 1):

The style would be conformant to Microsoft Best Practices, but you might consider not using the out parameter. Instead consider using an exception to handle the "error hitting domain server" problem.. so wrap the using in a try/catch block, and catching the "ErrorHittingDomainServer" exception and dealing it with appropriately.